# Idea on: $Y$ is $\tau-$measurable $\iff$ there $\exists c \in \mathbb R$ where $P(Y=c)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_{n})_{n}$ be independent random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and define $\tau:=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}\sigma(X_{n},X_{n+1},...)$ and let $Y$ be a real random variable.

Show:

$Y$ is $\tau-$measurable $\iff$ there $\exists c \in \mathbb R$ where $P(Y=c)=1$

I assume that $\Leftarrow$ is easier. Looking at the fact that $\exists c \in \mathbb R$ where $P(Y=c)=1$

$P(Y=c)=P(Y^{-1}(c))=1$ so this would mean that $Y^{-1}(c)\in \tau=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}\sigma(X_{n},X_{n+1},...)$ but then what can I say about any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: $Y^{-1}(A)$ is included in the set of $\mathbb{P}$-null sets if $c  \not \in A$, and in $\Omega$ without this set of  $\mathbb{P}$-null sets otherwise. You do not have any other assumptions on $\Omega$ and $\mathbb{P}$? or on $\tau$?

Comment: Do you know Kolmogorov's 0-1-law?

Comment: Yes for $A \in \tau: P(A)=0$ or $P(A)=1$ but that does not mean if I have $A$ such that $P(A)=0$ or $P(A)=1$ then $a \in \tau$

Comment: As was already pointed out by @Gâteau-Gallois, the assertion is wrong unless you impose further assumptions. Consider for instance $\Omega := [0,1]$ endowed with Lebesgue measure, $X_n := 0$ and $Y = 1_{\{0\}}$. Then $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=1$ but $Y$ is not $\tau$-measurable (since $\tau$ is the trivial $\sigma$ algebra).